Moment Ratios and L Moment Ratios:
I want to know the difference between moment ratio diagrams and L moment ratio diagrams.
As I understand  the moment ratio diagram serve the  purpose of detecting the type of probability density functions looking at the value of skewness and kurtosis coefficients.
What is the advantage of L moment ratios over moment ratio.
Why should order statistics be brought into consideration.
I am finding  it difficult to understand the grammar of  L moments
How are moment ratio diagrams and L moment  diagrams generated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The questions about the moment ratio diagrams and L moment ratio diagrams are very specific.

I want to know the basics.
